# Using promises/callbacks to wait for function to finish in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, server-side

I have a function which creates a database object out of three arrays. The arrays are filled in an each loop, one of the arrays relies on the value in the same iteration of the loop.

The dependent array uses the [requests](https://github.com/request/request) library and the [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) library to grab a string to populate the array with.

Currently the dependent array fills with nulls which I think is because the loop is not waiting for the request to be returned.

I am still learning and would like to get this to work without direct blocking to keep things asynchronous so I'm looking into promises/callbacks.

This is being done server-side but from what I've seen in cheerios docs there is no promises capability.

Here's what I have so far. (getFile() is the function that isn't filling the 'c' array, it also depends on the current value being put into 'b'). I do know that the getFile function gets the correct value with a console log test, so the issue must be in the implementation of filling 'c'.

addToDB() is a function which saves a value into mongoDB, from testing I know that the objects are correctly being put into the db, just the c array is not correct.

```
function getInfo(path) {
  $(path).each(function(i,e) {
    a.push(...)
    b.push(value)
    c.push(getFile(value))
  })
  var entry = new DB...//(a,b,c)
  addToDB(entry);
}

function getFile(...) {
  request(fullUrl, function (err, resp, page) {
    if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(page); // load the page
      srcEp = $(this).attr("src");
      return srcEp;
    } // end error and status code
  }); // end request
}
```

I've been reading about promises/callbacks and then() but I've yet to find anything which works.

Comment: I'm assuming that `addToDB()` is where your async operation is.  If so, then for us to help you solve this, you will have to show that code.  That's where the real change needs to take place.

Comment: addToDB is just a function that takes the arrays which have been populated and saves them. So it would have: var objectToMake = new... and then the save below it would be (through mongodb) objectToMake.save, the async I believe (still learning js, not sure if this is the issue) is the array c is not being populated, that is the each loop is not waiting for getFile to finish

Comment: Where's your async operation?  What are you waiting for to finish?  Your question talks about waiting for something to finish, but doesn't say what operation to wait for (and show the code for that operation).  Promises only help you solve a problem if you have an async operation.  Otherwise, synchronous operations just run in order.

Comment: Does `getFile()` make an asynchronous call? Can you show what it looks like? If it is asynchronous, it cannot return a value like that, but it could return a promise.

Comment: I should've clarified, the getFile function is making a request, and returning the results

Comment: for getFile, it is using the value from the b array on the current iteration of the loop to make a request and uses cheerio to parse a string that I want to populate the c array with

Comment: Then, show us the `getFile()` code.  You don't seem to get that you have NOT shown the most relevant portion of the code - the portion that makes an asynchronous request somewhere.  We cannot help you until you describe and disclose the asynchronous part of your code.

Comment: And, if you don't understand which of your operations are synchronous and which are asynchronous (or even what the difference is between those two types of operations), then that will be the place to start because none of this can be solved until that is understood.  Saving to a remote database or getting a remote file (basically any operation involving the network) is most likely asynchronous.

Comment: This is what the getFile function is doing: 

request(fullUrl, function (err, resp, page) {
    if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(page); // load the page
        srcEp = $(this).attr("src");
        return srcEp;
    } // end error and status code
}); // end request

Comment: Please use the edit link below your question to ADD this `getFile()` code to your question.  That is very relevant to your question and is required for people to understand what you are doing.  I would also guess that the `addToDB()` function may also have an async component.

Comment: Do I detect jQuery in there?

Comment: I looked into jQuery but this is running in server side, I am using the cheerio library however which has some core jQuery implementation for the server side. I haven't found any deferred or promises however. [cheerio](http://cheeriojs.github.io/cheerio/). I have been looking into [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) and it seems like it could have potential but I'm not sure how it works yet.

Comment: Is `paths` a js Array or a cheero object?

Comment: It's a csspath string I use it for loading the cheerio as: $ = cheerio.load

Comment: OK, I've not used cheerio before. I think I've got it now. Answer in preparation ...

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get your mind around the fact that any process that relies, at least in part, on an asynchronous sub-process, is itself inherently asynchronous.

At the lowest level of this question's code, `request()` is asynchronous, therefore its caller, `getFile()` is asynchronous, and its caller, `getInfo()` is also asynchronous.

Promises are an abstraction of the outcome of asynchronous processes and help enormously in coding the actions to be taken when such processes complete - successfully or under failure.

Typically, low-level asynchronous functions should return a promise to be acted on by their callers, which will, in turn, return a promise to their callers, and so on up the call stack. Inside each function, returned promise(s) may be acted on using promise methods, chiefly `.then()`, and may be aggregated using `Promise.all()` for example (syntax varies).

In this question, there is no evidence that `request()` currently returns a promise. You have three options :

- discover that `request()` does, in fact, return a promise.
- rewrite `request()` to return a promise.
- write an adapter function (a "promisifier") that calls `request()`, and generates/returns the promise, which is later fulfilled or rejected depending on the outcome of `request()`.

The first or second options would be ideal but the safe assumption for me (Roamer) is to assume that an adapter is required. Fortunately, I know enough from the question to be able to write one. `Cheerio` appears not to include jQuery's promise implementation, so a dedicated promise lib will be required.

Here is an adapter function, using syntax that will work with the Bluebird lib or native js promises:

```
//Promisifier for the low level function request()
function requestAsync(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(err, resp, page) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                if (resp.statusCode !== 200) {
                    reject(new Error('request error: ' + resp.statusCode));
                }
            } else {
                resolve(page);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Now `getFile(...)` and `getInfo()` can be written to make use of the promises returned from the lowest level's adapter.

```
//intermediate level function
function getFile(DOMelement) {
    var fullUrl = ...;//something derived from DOMelement. Presumably either .val() or .text()
    return requestAsync(fullUrl).then(function (page) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(page);
        srcEp = $(???).attr('src');//Not too sure what the selector should be. `$(this)` definitely won't work.
        return srcEp;
    });
}

//high level function
function getInfo(path) {
    var a = [], b = [], c = [];//presumably

    // Now map the $(path) to an array of promises by calling getFile() inside a .map() callback.
    // By chaining .then() a/b/c are populated when the async data arrives. 
    var promises = $(path).map(function(i, e) {
        return getFile(e).then(function(srcEp) {
            a[i] = ...;
            b[i] = e;
            c[i] = srcEp;
        });
    });
    //return an aggregated promise to getInfo's caller,
    //in case it needs to take any action on settlement.
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
        //What to do when all promises are fulfilled
        var entry = new DB...//(a,b,c)
        addToDB(entry);
    }, function(error) {
        //What to do if any of the promises fails
        console.log(error);
        //... you may want to do more.
    });
}
```